# subgroup of $\Bbb Z_5\times\Bbb Z_{25}$ is characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H =\langle(1,0),(0,5)\rangle$, prove that $H\subset \Bbb Z_5\times \Bbb Z_{25}$ is characteristic.

Let's say that $f\in \operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_5×\Bbb Z_{25})$. $f$ is homomorphism so it pass generator to generator. so if we look at $g = f|_H$ than $g(1,0) = (1,0)$.

How to continue from here?

Comment: Do you really mean $*$ or do you mean $\times$? In the latter case, I'd say $H$ is the smallest subgroup containing all elements of order $5$ and therefore characteristic

Comment: How many elements of order $5$ do the groups have?

Comment: $f(1,0)=(1,0)$ is not necessarily true

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I edited the question.

Comment: I mean, an automorphism maps generators to generators but it does not map every generator to itself. This would imply every automorphism is the identity, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Show that $H$ consists of all elements in the group of order $5$ (as well as the identity element $(0,0)$).

Comment: and then what? I believe I'm missing something

Comment: @user7080065 If $f$ is an automorphism (or just any injective homomorphism), then $f(x)$ and $x$ has the same order for any $x$.

Comment: so that means that every element in $f(x)$ will be of order 5 and therefor in H... thanks!

Comment: @user7080065 You still have to prove the proposition in my previous comment (unless you already have), but yes, basically, for any $h\in H$, $h$ has order $5$ (or $1$, that's easy to forget), so so does $f(h)$. And, of course, for $g\notin H$, the order is $25$, as is the order of $f(g)$.